# How to get the PDB id of a mystery sequence?

Tags: biopython

I have a bunch of proteins, from something called proteinnet.
Now the sequences there have some sort of ID, but it is clearly not a PDB id, so I need to find that in some other way. For each protein I have the amino acid sequence. I'm using biopython, but I'm not very experienced in it yet and couldn't find this in the guide.

So my question is how do I find a proteins PDB id given that I have the amino acid sequence of the protein? (Such that I can download the PDB file for the protein)

Comment: According to the documentation (https://github.com/aqlaboratory/proteinnet/blob/master/docs/proteinnet_records.md) "ProteinNet Records are currently provided in two file formats," The machine readable format uses an ID of this type:  [ID] <class>#<pdb_id>_<chain_number>_<chain_id>  . How exactly do you get your "bunch of proteins"?

Comment: That is unfortunately only for the training data that it has that format, for the test data, the IDs are given as:
TBM#T0760,
Unclassified#T0798
...
Which are clearly not a PDB ID

Comment: https://search.rcsb.org/#building-search-request : sequence  This service employs the MMseqs2 software and performs fast sequence matching searches (BLAST-like) based on a user-provided FASTA sequence (with E-value or % Identity cutoffs). Following search targets are available:

    pdb_protein_sequence: all current protein sequences in PDB
    pdb_dna_sequence: all current DNA sequences in PDB
    pdb_rna_sequence: all current RNA sequences in PDB

Comment: use biopython blast module and select pdb as target database for search

Comment: I will test out the biopython blast module tomorrow and see whether it can do what I need, cheers!

Comment: I managed to make it sorta work with the online PDB, which is fine if I only want to do a few sequences.

Answer (score 1):

hi I was playing a little bit ago with the RCSB PDB search API,

ended up with this piece of code (can't find examples on rcsb pdb website anymore),

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Dec 27 16:20:43 2020

@author: Pietro
"""



import PDB_searchAPI_5
from PDB_searchAPI_5.rest import ApiException

import json

#"value":"STEYKLVVVGAGGVGKSALTIQLIQNHFVDEYDPTIEDSYRKQVVIDGETCLLDILDTAGQEEYSAMRDQYMRTGEGFLCVFAINNTKSFEDIHQYREQIKRVKDSDDVPMVLVGNKCDLAARTVESRQAQDLARSYGIPYIETSAKTRQGVEDAFYTLVREIRQHKLRKLNPPDESGPGCMSCKCVLS"



# Defining the host is optional and defaults to https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1
# See configuration.py for a list of all supported configuration parameters.
configuration = PDB_searchAPI_5.Configuration(
    host = "http://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1"
)


  
data_entry_1 = '''{
  "query": {
    "type": "terminal",
    "service": "sequence",
    "parameters": {
      "evalue_cutoff": 1,
      "identity_cutoff": 0.9,
      "target": "pdb_protein_sequence",
      "value": "STEYKLVVVGAGGVGKSALTIQLIQNHFVDEYDPTIEDSYRKQVVIDGETCLLDILDTAGQEEYSAMRDQYMRTGEGFLCVFAINNTKSFEDIHQYREQIKRVKDSDDVPMVLVGNKCDLAARTVESRQAQDLARSYGIPYIETSAKTRQGVEDAFYTLVREIRQHKLRKLNPPDESGPGCMSCKCVLS"


    }
  },
  "request_options": {
    "scoring_strategy": "sequence"
  },
  "return_type": "entry"
}'''  




# Enter a context with an instance of the API client
with PDB_searchAPI_5.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = PDB_searchAPI_5.SearchServiceApi(api_client)
    
    try:
        # Get RCSB PDB data schema as JSON schema extended with RCSB metadata.
        pippo = api_instance.run_json_queries_get(data_entry_1)
              
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling SearchServiceApi->run_json_queries_get: %s\n" % e)
        exit()
        

  
print(type(pippo))

print(dir(pippo))

pippox = pippo.__dict__

print('\n bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \n' ,pippox)

print('\n\n ********************************* \n\n')

print(type(pippox))

pippoy = pippo.result_set

print(type(pippoy))

for i in pippoy:
    print('\n',i,'\n', type(i))
    
print('\n LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL\n')
    
for i in pippoy:
    for key  in i:
        print('\n', i['identifier'], '   score : ', i['score'])
```

the search module (`import PDB_searchAPI_5`) was generated with: openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar [link here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.3.1/)

the open api specs where 1.7.3 now they are 1.7.15 see https://search.rcsb.org/openapi.json

the  data_entry_1 bit was copied from rcsb pdb website but can't find it anymore,
it was saying  something about [mmseqs2](https://mmseqs.com/latest/userguide.pdf) being the sofware doing the search, played with:

```
"evalue_cutoff": 1,
"identity_cutoff": 0.9,
```

parameters but didn't find a way to select only 100% identity

[here the PDB_searchAPI_5](https://easyupload.io/d9uelw)     install it in a virtual enviroment with:

`pip install PDB-searchAPI-5-1.0.0.tar.gz`

was generated by openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar  with:

`java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate -g python -i pdb-search-api-openapi.json --additionalproperties=generateSourceCodeOnly=True,packageName=PDB_searchAPI_5`

don't put spaces in --additionalproperties part (took one week to figure it out)

the `README.md` file is the most important part as it explain how to use the OPEN-API client

you need your fasta sequences here:
`"value":"STEYKLVVVGAGGVGKSALTIQLIQNHFVDEYDPTIEDSYRKQVVIDGETCLLDILDTAGQEEYSAMRDQYMRTGEGFLCVFAINNTKSFEDIHQYREQIKRVKDSDDVPMVLVGNKCDLAARTVESRQAQDLARSYGIPYIETSAKTRQGVEDAFYTLVREIRQHKLRKLNPPDESGPGCMSCKCVLS"`

the score = 1 should be the exact match,

probably the biopython blast module is easier, but it blast NIH database instead of RCSB PDB,  sorry can't elaborate more on this, still need to figure out what is a JSON file, and wasnt able to find a better free tool that automatically generate a better OPEN-API python client (I believe is kind of not so easy task... but we always want more...)

to get API documentation try:

`java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate -g html -i https://search.rcsb.org/openapi.json  --skip-validate-spec`

You get html document or for pdf: https://mrin9.github.io/RapiPdf/

`http://search.rcsb.org/openapi.json` 
works as well as `https://search.rcsb.org/openapi.json`  so that you can look at the exchanges between client and server with wireshark